# Datatables filter date range without using any datatables plugin

Tags: jquery, datatable, datepicker, datatables, date-range

Following is my html structure

```
<div class="filters">
    <input type="text" name="hireDate" id="hireDate">
    <input type="text" name="terminationDate" id="terminationDate">
</div>

<table id="exampleTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Employee Name</th>
        <th>Hire Date</th>
        <th>Termination Date</th>
        <th>Designation </th>
        <th> Hire Date epoch </th>
        <th> Termination Date epoch </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- table data here -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to filter table data based on hireDate and terminationDate selected

1. If user selects `HireDate` and `terminationDate` as `1-jan-2016`,
   `31-jan-2016` respectively, Then table should show all rows which
   has `HireDate >= 1-jan-2016` and `TerminationDate <= 31-jan-2016`
2. If user selected only `HireDate` then table should show only rows
   which has `HireDate >= userSelectedHireDate`
3. If user selected only `TerminationDate` then table should show only
   rows which has `TerminationDate <= userSelectedTerminationDate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is my approach through which I have resolved this issue

```
var dataTable = $('#exampleTable').DataTable({
    "columnDefs" : [{
                "targets":[4, 5],
                "visible":false,
            }],
 });

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var startDate = $('#hireDate').val();
        //convert date into epoch
        startDate = (startDate == '') ? -1 : moment(startDate, 'MMMM DD, YYYY').valueOf()/1000;

        var endDate = $('#terminationDate').val();
        endDate = (endDate == '') ? -1 : moment(endDate, 'MMMM DD, YYYY').valueOf()/1000;

        var tableStartDate = (data[4] == '--') ? 0 : data[4];
        var tableEndDate = (data[5] == '--') ? 1 : data[5];

        //Show all rows if start and end date is not selected
        if(startDate == -1 && endDate == -1) {
            return true;
        }

        if(tableStartDate >= startDate) {
            if(endDate == -1) {
                return true;
            }

            if(tableEndDate != 1 && tableEndDate <= endDate){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
);


$('#hireDate').on('change', function(){
    $('#exampleTable').dataTable().api().column(1).search('', true, false).draw();
});

$('#terminationDate').on('change', function(){
    $('#exampleTable').dataTable().api().column(2).search('', true, false).draw();
});
```